# Error of Adam Bashford (order 4) Used with Runge-Kutta (order 4)

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have approximated up to t=2 with step sizes h=(1/2)^n for n=1,...,10 using a Adam-Bashford (order 4) that uses the Runge-Kutta (order 4) method to determine the starting values. I've run my MATLAB code for a few examples and they match. However, when I look at my absolute errors for y(2), I find that the next error isn't 1/16 of the previous error, which I think it should be, since I'm increasing step size of 1/2 and the order should be C(h^4).

Am I wrong that the error should be C(h^4)?

Comment: What kind of loop control do you use in the AB loop? In some variants the accumulation of floating point errors in the time updates leads to one step more which gives an $O(h)$ error.

Comment: It would help the guessing process if you could add a table or a log plot of $n\to$ error or a loglog of $h\to$ error.